# Vector space of holomorphic functions on the extended complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $V$ be the vector space of functions that are holomorphic on the extended complex plane except possibly at the points $0$ and $i$, where they have poles of order at most two. What is the dimension of $V$ ? Give an explicit basis for this vector space.

I don't really know where to start with this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $g(z)=z^{2}(z-i)^{2}f(z)$ is an entire function. Also $f$ is bounded near $\infty$ so $|g(z)|\leq C|z|^{4}$ for some constant $C$. This implies that $g(z)$ is  a polynomial of degree at most $4$. Hence $f(z)=\frac {p(z)} {z^{2}(z-i)^{2}}$. Just use  a basis for  polynomials of degree at most $4$.

Comment: How do you start with the function $z^2 (z - i)^2 f(z)$?

Comment: @Airdish That helps you to get rid of the poles.

Comment: What's the justification for $g$ being a polynomial?

Comment: @Airdish If $g$ is entire and $|g(z)| \leq C |z|^{n}$ for $z|$ sufficiently large then $g$ is  a polynomial of degree at most $n$. This has appeared many times on this site so I am not repeating the proof. Please search the site for a proof.